# PHPExcel different behavior on different systems

Tags: phpexcel

I have PHPExcel on localhost and on server. 
When I try to read xlsx file on localhost - all ok, but when I try to read same file on server - all cells with cyrillic words are empty.

All systems have same PHPExcel and PHP versions.

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Check the dependencies, like mb_*

Comment: Thanks Mark! But after some experiments I have same problem on localhost. I have xlsx file, if I try to read it with PHPExcel - I get empty cells with cyrillic words, but if I open and save file with MS Office and then try to read - all ok. It seems that MS Office corrects some error when saving a file. Is there a chance to read the file with PHPExcel without resaving file in MS Office? Or is this an unsolvable problem?

Comment: PHPExcel does this perfectly well for thpousands of people.... if it doesn't work for you then I need specifics..... It's unsolvable unless you give me some details to figure out what is happening.... Are you letting PHPExcel identify the file type and confirming that it is really an OfficeOpenXML file.... if not, what is it?

Comment: PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify() returns Excel2007, I uploaded xlsx file (2Mb), hope It helps to resolve problem: http://expirebox.com/download/cbc72b784176cc8cba82deced5fd08d2.html,

Comment: In this file second column (row 10-20 for example) has cells with cyrillic words, that PHPExcel reads as empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this file is that it was created by an application that doesn't recognise case-sensitivity in filenames.

The `rels` table indicates that the Shared Strings table (where all the text string values for the workbook are stored) is called `sharedStrings.xml`, but the actual file in the zip is called `SharedStrings.xml`. A file generated by MS Excel itself uses the correct case in the filename, so I'm guessing that this file was created using some third-party tool or library. MS Excel is clearly more forgiving about case-sensitivity in filenames, allowing it to read the zip regardless.

I can probably fix this by using

```
$zip->getFromIndex(
    $zip->locateName('sharedStrings.xml', ZIPARCHIVE::FL_NOCASE);
);
```

rather than

```
$zip->getFromName('sharedStrings.xml');
```

but it will take me a couple of days to implement the fix

**EDIT**

Somewhere around line 310 of the `/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php` file is the `getFromZipArchive()` method that can be changed to read:

```
private function getFromZipArchive($archive, $fileName = '')
{
    // Root-relative paths
    if (strpos($fileName, '//') !== false) {
        $fileName = substr($fileName, strpos($fileName, '//') + 1);
    }
    $fileName = PHPExcel_Shared_File::realpath($fileName);

    // Apache POI fixes
    $contents = $archive->getFromIndex(
        $archive->locateName($fileName, ZIPARCHIVE::FL_NOCASE)
    );
    if ($contents === false) {
        $contents = $archive->getFromIndex(
            $archive->locateName(substr($fileName, 1), ZIPARCHIVE::FL_NOCASE)
        );
    }

    return $contents;
}
```

and will then be able to access the Shared String file case-insensitively

Comment: Thank you very much!
Product support at the highest level.